# Getting data from my database without full page reload

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

My webapp has looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUry7.png)

I have a model with detailed job information and I'm already able to populate and build that table on the left with specific data from the model. Though, there is significantly more data on each job.  I would like to be able have the right panel (where the red box is) update based on what table row has been selected. I know that I don't want to reload the whole page. I know enough to know that this requires jQuery or JS and AJAX.  I've just started learning jQuery so searching for answers has been difficult.

I found [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762629/pass-information-from-javascript-to-django-app-and-back) who seems to be requesting the same thing as me but the answer is apparently no longer valid given significant updates to django, so says a comment.

my model is like:

```
   class Jobs(models.Model):
    jobnum = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=False, null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=True)
    recruits = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=True)
    .....more stuff....
        def __unicode__(self): #python 3.3. is __str__
            return self.jobnum
```

So say i wanted to click the table row for Job 99 and have it show the value of 'recruits' that I have for it in the database in the red bordered box on the right. How would I do this?

Comment: This does indeed appear to be a duplicate of that question; the comment there is only pointing out that Django doesn't include simplejson any more, which is fine as you can either install it yourself or just use the built in json library.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, how would the answer be modified to include using the built in json library?

Comment: Er, by replacing references to simplejson with json.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, ok, he says to put in the view: 
"from django.utils import simplejson"
So i put in:
"from django.utils import json" but get:

Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value: 
cannot import name 'json'

Comment: @Brandon, a lot of things. I'm very new to django and also only started learning python a little over a month ago so this is a very difficult task. I'm often times not sure what I've found on the web is current and if I do run the code I'm unable to diagnose what I've done wrong.

Comment: The [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762629/pass-information-from-javascript-to-django-app-and-back) is not necessarily the best approach here. Assume the table can be built to include all the necessary data (hidden if necessary), then the solution will be 100% client-side - no AJAX necessary. If the table can built like that, then I can write the jQuery (as can many others).

Comment: @Roamer-1888, While it would be easier an easier solution now I'd rather not do it that way as that could potentially pose issues when scaling this later. Also, it'd be good for me to learn and get acquainted with ajaxing.

Comment: I'm not sure what type of scaling you have in mind but I would guess that my approach would be no simpler or harder to scale than an AJAX approach.